# How to increment sequential Const values when adding a new one in the middle

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a code like this

```
const
value1 = 1;
value2 = 2;
value4 = 3;
.
.
.
valuen = n;
```

and say I want to add `value3 = 3;` to the list without having to deal with the pain of editing all the values to n.

Is there a intrinsic method or a trick that can be done to make this easier in the future?

Comment: No. There's no IDE magic that will renumber constants for you. You'll need to edit them yourself, or use a different data type (like a constant array, for instance).

Comment: @KenWhite you killed my dream, I have a list of 1245 consts and I want to add this at position 100 so thank you, I better start.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot of constants. But that doesn't change the fact that the IDE has no built-in support for this functionality, I'm afraid. :-)

Comment: Write a program to do this. This is exactly why you learn a language like Python so you can do this in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Use an enum if you don't mind typecasting. type
  TValues = (value1 = 1, value2, value3, ...);

Comment: @SertacAkyuz enums can hold 1245 consts!!! I thought they are only good for 256 tops

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will consider this. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097201/enumerated-type-limit-to-number-of-items

Comment: You don't need to type cast, use the Ord operator

Comment: Also, since the values don't seem to matter you can just use an enum full stop.

Comment: It's slightly embarassing, but I'd use Excel for this: Replace all ` = ` with tabstops and copy it over to an empty Excel sheet. Then use the column autofill feature and so on...

Comment: @Uli No reason at all to be embarrassed about a quick and effective solution to a problem!

Comment: @UliGerhardt I have done wonders with excel before and what you suggested is no less than that, thank you

Comment: A dirty trick: Select all lines of constants you want to increment. Make a _Search & Replace_ for ";" to "+1;" with scope _current selection_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Delphi editor.

- Step 1: Add the new const variable in its right place:

  ```
  const
    value1 = 1;
    value2 = 2;
    value3 =
    value4 = 3;
    value5 = 4;
    value6 = 5;
    value7 = 6;
  ```
- Step 2: Use the **column** block selection shortcut to select from 3 to the end of the list.
  To turn on column mode selection, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and mark the block. Alternatively, drag the mouse with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key down.

[image]

- Step 3: Cut and paste the section to one line up.

[image]

- Step 4: Finally, enter the last value. Job done in a couple of seconds.

[image]

Comment: Where were you yesterday?, I'm about to cry because of this answer

Comment: So I be happy, I reverted the file to an old version and tried this, It is wonderful and it really takes seconds. thank you

Comment: Please add that the shortcut is ctrl + O + C

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to update the values of the consts if they are defined that way and if a new value is inserted somewhere in the middle. But see below: there are ways to achieve this.

#### Enumerations

But you could use an enumeration instead:

```delphi
type
  ValueType = (
    value1 = 1,   // 1
    value2,       // 2
    value4,       // 3
    ...
    valuen);      // n
```

You can easily add a `value3`, and all subsequent values shift accordingly:

```delphi
type
  ValueType = (
    value1 = 1,   // 1
    value2,       // 2
    value3,       // 3
    value4,       // now: 4
    ...
    valuen);      // now: n+1
```

This also makes them typesafe. Of course, if you really want to use them as integers, you will have to cast: `Integer(value3)` (to read or write) or use `Ord(value3)` (to read). But you would typically use them directly as enumerations. You can also easily create sets out of these, which is much harder with constants.

#### Constants

Of course, if you *really* want to use constants, you can do what others do in such circumstances:

```delphi
const
  value1 = 1;              // 1
  value2 = value1 + 1;     // 2
  value4 = value2 + 1;     // 3
  value5 = value4 + 1;     // 4
  // etc...
```

Now, if you want to add a `value3`, you'll only have to update a few values:

```delphi
const
  value1 = 1;          // 1
  value2 = value1 + 1; // 2 
  value3 = value2 + 1; // new: 3
  value4 = value3 + 1; // modified: 4 
  value5 = value4 + 1; // now: 5
  // etc...
```

This is of course less typesafe and requires more work.

#### Parameters that require bitwise operations

For an API that always expects an integral type or even or-ed/and-ed combinations of such integers, and which I can't modify, I would use integral constants again:

```delphi
type
  Flags = Cardinal;
const
  Flag1 = 1;           // 1
  Flag2 = Flag1 shl 1; // 2
  Flag3 = Flag2 shl 1; // 4
  Flag4 = Flag3 shl 1; // 8
  // etc.
```

Used like:

```delphi
MyAPIFunc('Hello, world', Flag1 or Flag3 or Flag4);
```

Comment: Idiom is to use `Ord()` to obtain ordinal value of an enum value

Comment: For now I'm painfully editing the consts by myself, but I think the first option would be more appropriate for the future (I wonder how the Guys at emba are editing control messages when they want to add new ones).

Comment: @Nasreddine: David is right. If they add a new one, they don't want the others to change their values.

Comment: There's really no scenario where you need to integer cast. Use Ord to go from enum to ordinal. Cast to the enumerated type to go in the other direction. I'm not sure why you are so attached to that cast.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think when you want to code things like this you want the names to be in the same category, the numbers really do not matter because in code you are using the names to send and receive.

Comment: @David: I am not really attached to the cast, but if you want an integer, it is not uncommon to cast to one.

Comment: It's idiomatic to prefer `Ord()`

Comment: @David: whatever. Does it matter?

Comment: When an enumerated type is used in place of constants, the purpose for a possible cast would be to disclose the integer value that a particular constant should represent, rather than it's ordinality. IMO.

Comment: qSertac: that was my thinking too. But note that Ord() does in fact do nothing. It results in absolutely no generated code, except perhaps an expansion to 32 bit. It is like a cast to Integer, so you always get the same value. But ISTM that a cast to Integer sometimes indicates the intent a little better.

Comment: Generally one avoids using casts because they can often subvert the type system. So `Ord()` is only valid when the argument is an ordinal type, but `Integer()` can accept more types. Obviously the end result is identical in terms of the behaviour, if an ordinal is provided. But if, say, a pointer is provided, then `Ord()` results in compilation error, `Integer()` does not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Succ()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Succ) function. Of course, using enumerations are easier to understand, but this is the direct answer to your question.

Example:

```
const
  value1 = 1;
  value2 = succ(value1);
  value4 = succ(succ(value2));
  value5 = succ(value4);
  value6 = succ(value5);
```

To insert `Value3`, you have only to change `value4` and leave `value5` and `value6` unchanged.:

```
const
  value1 = 1;
  value2 = succ(value1);
  value3 = succ(value2);
  value4 = succ(value3);
  value5 = succ(value4);
```

Comment: This is in essence a subset of Rudy's answer.

Comment: I tried using this, but I have one problem with it takes readability away (what if the difference between v2 an v4 is 5? ), Thank you for your help